# zoo visitor tags being wrapped in p tags

Tags: zoo-visitor

I am using Zoo Visitor and when I try and display my members the visitor:member_firstname and visitor:member_lastname have mysterious < p > tags around them.  Based on my code below they should be on a singel line in a h2 tag, but instead they are on 2 lines each wrapped with a paragraph tag

```
{exp:zoo_visitor:members limit="99"}
<div id="profile" onclick="location.href='{homepage}';"  style="cursor:pointer;">
<h2> {visitor:member_firstname} {visitor:member_lastname}</h2>
</div><!--END profile --> 
{/exp:zoo_visitor:members}
```

Comment: Have you checked your firstname and lastname zoo visitor fields to see if default text formatting is set to 'none'?